# How to pass dates as parameters in Ajax url get call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, viewbag

I have an Ajax call that tries to populate a `highchart` by calling an `api`. I am trying to access date values from `ViewBag` and passing them to the `AJAX` url, I end up getting an error

> jQuery.Deferred exception: Jun is not defined ReferenceError: Jun is
> not defined

the value from the ViewBag looks like `June-2022`. The ajax implementation looks like

```
  $.ajax({
             url: 'api/getProvinceData/'+ @ViewBag.reportinPeriod,
             type: 'GET',
             success: function (data) { }
        });
```

so the complete api with the values filled up should look like when it gets the value in the ViewBag

```
 url: 'api/getProvinceData/Jun-2022'
```

Why am I getting Jun is undefined in Ajax, while I am just accessing the value directly from the ViewBag? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I would look at the @ViewBag.reportingPeriod object in the console, and see if you need to parse it in some way. It may be returning more than just a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because  you are calling a view it will render it as  `'api/getProvinceData/'+ Jun-2020,` so the best way to access it is to just have it inside the quotes and not concatenate it so it will be

```
$.ajax({
             url:  'api/getProvinceData/@ViewBag.reportinPeriod',
             type: 'GET',
             success: function (data) { }
        });
```

and it will make the api correctly as

```
 'api/getProvinceData/June-2022
```